# Can I use the same gitlab-runner for Multiple gitlab instances?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two separate git-lab instances on separate networks. Can I use the same runner for each of them? Assuming, both git-lab instances can access the server with the runner on it. Is it possible to use one runner for both of my instances of git-lab? I have read most of the git-lab documentation about runners and it doesn't seem to talk about this scenario, at-least from what I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define one runner section for each registration: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

The url and token are configured at the runner level, so **yes** you can register the same runner on different GitLab URLs.

Comment: Excellent, i suspected as much. In order to set this up do i simply edit the `TOML` file for my current runner and add another `url` and `token` tag with the second gitlab instance under the `[[runner]]` section? Thanks for the help.

Comment: After further consideration, it seems like what your saying is that I would simply create another `[[runner]]` section in the `TOML` file and add my other `url` and `token` for the second gitlab instance?

Comment: @slappy_sloth Run the registration command twice with the required parameters for the different instances. Keep in mind the `token` in the `toml` file is not the GitLab registration token, but the token you get after registering it. Ref. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#one-line-registration-command

Comment: Could you post a sample TOML file with multiple (redacted/bogus) tokens? Also, my TOML file doesn't have a `[[runner]]` section, and the GitLab docs don't mention anything about a `[[runner]]` section. I think you mean `[[runners]]`.